# Get the list numbers from Word document?

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to parse a Word 2010 document.  I'm grabbing all the text from every cell in the first column of every table on every page.  The problem I'm having, though, is that when I get the text, it's not including the list numbers.  For example, the text in my table looks like this:
  [image]

My program loops through the document and grabs the text from every cell in the first column.  Instead of getting "1. Introduction", though, I'm getting "Introduction".  Here's what the data looks like that I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see, I'm not getting the list numbers, just the text (i.e. "Introduction" instead of "1. Introduction").

Here's the loop I'm using to get the data:

```
        // Loop through each table in the document, 
        // grab only text from cells in the first column
        // in each table.
        foreach (Table tb in docs.Tables)
        {
            for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                var cell = tb.Cell(row, 1);
                var text = cell.Range.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(text);
            }
        }
```

Can someone offer any pointers on how to grab the list numbers from each cell, as well as the text?  I imagine it will be something like this:

```
var text = cell.Range.ListNumber + " " + cell.Range.Text;
```

...but I can't figure it out, exactly.

Comment: these number are listing numbers right?

Comment: I'm assuming they are.  In the document, they're there just to form an outline.  I'm not sure what they're called, as far as the interop is concerned.  I was thinking list numbers or outline numbers, but I can't be sure of the terminology.  I was hoping that when I grabbed the text from the cell, the numbers would come too.  That isn't the case, though.  They're being treated as separate and I don't know how to get to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer.  I had to get the ListString value:

```
        // Loop through each table in the document, 
        // grab only text from cells in the first column
        // in each table.
        foreach (Table tb in docs.Tables)
        {
            for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                var cell = tb.Cell(row, 1);
                var listNumber = cell.Range.ListFormat.ListString;
                var text = listNumber + " " + cell.Range.Text;

                dt.Rows.Add(text);
            }
        }
```